# Putting a Perl array into a hash

Tags: arrays, perl

I am writing a script that parses a file and want the entire result in an array.  I ran into a problem that I boiled down to the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @sections  = ();
my @sections1 = qw/sect1 sect2 sect3/;
my @sections2 = qw/sect4 sect5/;

my @textbooks = ();

my $text1 = { title => "title1", author => "author1" };
my $text2 = { title => "title2", author => "author2" };

for ( @sections1 ) {
  push(@sections, $_);
}
$text1->{sections} = \@sections;
@sections = ();

for ( @sections2 ) {
  push(@sections, $_);
}

push(@textbooks, $text1);
$text2->{sections} = \@sections;
print Dumper($text2);

push(@textbooks, $text2);

print Dumper(@textbooks);
```

The result of the first print Dumper is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'title' => 'title2',
          'sections' => [
                          'sect4',
                          'sect5'
                        ],
          'author' => 'author2'
        }
```

and the result of the second one is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'sections' => [
                          'sect4',
                          'sect5'
                        ],
          'title' => 'title1',
          'author' => 'author1'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'title' => 'title2',
          'sections' => $VAR1->{'sections'},
          'author' => 'author2'
        };
```

I have two questions on this which I'm sure are related.

- I realized that the first sections are a reference so that they contains what I would expect the second sections.  I thought that the line `@sections=()` would create a new array and a new reference would be made later.  Obviously I'm not thinking of this correctly.
- What's going on with the second sections? From the output of `$text2` it appears correct until the push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entirely correct:

```
@sections = ();
```

does *NOT* create a new array, it overwrites the content of the old.

One of the things `Data::Dumper` 'hides' is the references.

Try this:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %{$text2} ) { 
   print $key, $text2 -> {$key},"\n"
}
```

And:

```
foreach my $thing (@textbooks) {
    print "TB ref $thing\n";
    foreach my $key ( keys %{$thing} ) {
        print "$key => ", $thing->{$key}, "\n";
    }
}
```

From the latter, you'll get something like:

```
TB ref HASH(0x12de994)
sections => ARRAY(0x12e43b4)
author => author1
title => title1
TB ref HASH(0x12de9ac)
sections => ARRAY(0x12e43b4)
title => title2
author => author2
```

Note how the array has the same ID here -  this is the root of your problem. Your hash has the same reference twice. (The parent `hashes` in your array of hashes differ)

An easy workaround might be to switch from using `@sections` to `$sections`, because whilst:

```
@sections = ();
```

Doesn't make a 'new' data structure:

```
$sections = [];
```

Will because `[]` is an anonymous array, you're creating, and just reassigning the reference.

The other solution is to generally narrow down the scope with `my`, but with your code that won't work so well - works nicely with `foreach` loops though.

Answer (score 1):

`\@sections` is a reference to `@sections` container (array).

`@sections = ()` doesn't create new array, but empties old one. To check whether two variables are identical, compare their references,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sections = 1 .. 3;
my $ref1 = \@sections;
@sections = ();

print "identical!\n" if $ref1 == \@sections;
```

Comment: Locally scoping with `my` to the smallest code block goes a fair way to 'reducing' this sort of problem. As does using an anon array ref.

Comment: @Sobrique yes, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's only one `@sections` array and, no matter what you do to its contents, the reference `\@sections` will refer to the same array

The dumper output shows you this

```
$VAR2 = {
          'title' => 'title2',
          'sections' => $VAR1->{'sections'},
          'author' => 'author2'
        };
```

is saying that `$VAR2->{sections}` is the same reference as `$VAR1->{sections}`, which is clearly true as they are both a reference to the same `@sections` array. The data it contains is simply a matter of how it was left after the latest modification. Here it is a copy of `@sections2` and will contain `('sect4', 'sect5')`

Some concepts that may help are

- You should declare your variables as *late* as possible, preferably at their first point of use
- You can write the loop

  ```
  for ( @sections1 ) {
    push(@sections, $_);
  }
  ```

  as just

  ```
  push @sections, @sections1
  ```
- Instead of

  ```
  $text1->{sections} = \@sections
  ```

  which assigns a reference to the array `@sections`, you can use

  ```
  $text1->{sections} = [ @sections ]
  ```

  which creates a new, anonymous array, populates it from the contents of `@sections`, and returns a reference to it. That leaves you free to modify `@sections` without changing the copy of the data that you have saved in `$text1`

Your code should probably be written something like this, but you haven't said anything about what you want to do with the data so you may need some changes

I highly recommend that you use [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) in preference to `Data::Dumper`. You may need to install it as it isn't a core module, but it is well worth it as the dump output is much neater, more concise, and readable

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @sections1 = qw/ sect1 sect2 sect3 /;
my @sections2 = qw/ sect4 sect5 /;

my @textbooks = (
  { title => 'title1', author => 'author1' },
  { title => 'title2', author => 'author2' },
);

$textbooks[0]{sections} = \@sections1;
$textbooks[1]{sections} = \@sections2;

dd \@textbooks;
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    author   => "author1",
    sections => ["sect1", "sect2", "sect3"],
    title    => "title1",
  },
  {
    author => "author2",
    sections => ["sect4", "sect5"],
    title => "title2",
  },
]
```

Comment: I knew that just using \@sections1 and \@sections2 would give me the desired result, however I'm using a loop and the arrays are filled from a file.  The anonymous array [] works great.

Comment: @PeterStaab: If you're defining the arrays from a file then — as I commented in my solution — you are declaring them with the wrong scope. If they were declared *inside* the loop that populates and uses them then you could simply take a reference as you did originally. That would be preferable to duplicating the information in an anonymous array, but without seeing the bigger picture I can't help you with specifics